# Iterating through nested Json Array and performing operations on String Java

Tags: java, json

I have json array in this format

```
    [
{
    "promise_detail": [
        {
            "promise_date": "15 OCT 2020",
            "promise_amount": "USD 1086",
            "status": "CANCELLED"
        }
    ],
    "promise_note": "hello"
}
```

]

My requirement is i need to loop through Json array and format promise amount field to two decimal places which looks like "USD 1086.00"

Here is what i am trying to do

```
    result = executeQueries.getPromiseHistoryDetails(promiseHistoryModel);//Here result is same Json Array as shown above
    for (int n = 0; n < result.length(); n++) {
            JSONObject object = result.getJSONObject(n);
            for(int k=0;k<object.length();k++) {  //struck here
                String promiseAmount = object.getJSONObject(k);
                Float amount=Float.parseFloat(promiseAmount);
                if (object.get("promise_amount") != null) {
                    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
                    df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
                    result.getJSONObject(n).put("promise_amount", df.format(amount));
                }
            }
            
        }
```

But I am getting some issues.I am struck at this point.Can anyone suggest me how i can achieve this.This is my expected output

```
    [
{
    "promise_detail": [
        {
            "promise_date": "15 OCT 2020",
            "promise_amount": "USD 1086.00",
            "status": "CANCELLED"
        }
    ],
    "promise_note": "hello"
}
]
```

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) is your friend.  It shows that DecimalFormat inherits two `format` methods from NumberFormat:  [format(double)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/text/NumberFormat.html#format(double)) and [format(long)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/text/NumberFormat.html#format(long)).  You are trying to format a String, but the methods only accept numbers.

Comment: @VGR Edited the question

Comment: Getting closer.  Now, it should be obvious from the exception you’re getting that the characters `USD` do not constitute a valid float value.  Use the [substring](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int)) method to obtain text consisting of only the numeric value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you mixed up the operation of `JSONArray` with `JSONObject`.  The inner for-loop is supposed to traverse a `JSONArray` rather than a `JSONObject`.

And the format of `promise_amount` in your given JSON string is a `String`, so you can just append `.00` to the origin value as follows:

**Code snippet**

```
for (int n = 0; n < result.length(); n++) {
    JSONArray object = result.getJSONObject(n).getJSONArray("promise_detail");
    for (int k = 0; k < object.length(); k++) {
        String promiseAmount = object.getJSONObject(k).getString("promise_amount");
        if (promiseAmount != null) {
            object.getJSONObject(k).put("promise_amount", String.format("%s.00", promiseAmount));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sachin HR Please let me know if my solution works for you, thanks!